# Errors detected when loading a vim plugin from .vimrc

Tags: python, editor, vi, vim

I have installed vim 7.3 on debian system along with some vimrc i have downloaded from internet. It used to work fine on my other debian machine but here i get these error messages while i load the vim editor.

Here are the errors:

```
Error detected while processing /home/tejinder/.vim/plugin/gundo.vim:
line  196:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: python << ENDPYTHON
line  197:
E492: Not an editor command: def asciiedges(seen, rev, parents):
line  199:
E121: Undefined variable: rev
E15: Invalid expression: rev not in seen:
line  221:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  231:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  233:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  235:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  238:
E690: Missing "in" after :for
line  347:
E690: Missing "in" after :for
line  356:
E690: Missing "in" after :for
line  453:
E690: Missing "in" after :for
line  464:
E690: Missing "in" after :for
line  469:
E133: :return not inside a function
line  795:
E170: Missing :endfor
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If anyone could figure out thats going on, please guide me. Thanks a lot.

Here is vimrc source:
https://github.com/mitsuhiko/dotfiles/tree/master/vim

Comment: Please provide the vimrc which produces the errors.

Comment: Please add the error here. That paste link will stop working in the future.

Comment: Provided the source for vimrc in original post.

Answer (score 6):

On debian install `vim-gnome` or `vim-nox` if you dont have X-server on system.

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-nox
```

These versions include python support for vim.

Answer (score 4):

The first error message is the one to look at: "python" isn't available in your vim.  You may have "vim-tiny" installed.  Try "apt-get install vim" to get a larger build.  Also, in vim, you can use the ":version" command to see all the options, and whether each is compiled in or not.  Your current vim will have "-python" (meaning no python, as opposed to "+python") in the list displayed.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that the default debian vim 7.3 packages doesn't have python support. I compiled the source code with python support and now it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your VIM has no python support compiled in. Unfortunately I cannot help about what to do with that distribution because I'm a true master about messing up linux systems by manually installing stuff conflicting with the package system.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that the default debian vim 7.3 packages doesn't have python support. I compiled the source code with python support and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Python version 2.4 or better?

Test this by running

```
python --version
```

at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

vim 7.3 is the very latest version of vim. I think, you are using with your old .vimrc files. One good method to troubleshoot would be, move your `~/.vim` to `~/.vim_backup` and load the vim 7.3 so that uses the system default vimrc.  See if you still get those errors. and load only the plugins which you want with 7.3 in your new `.vimrc`

Comment: vimrc is quite update too. And moreover it runs fine on other system with vim 7.3 too.

Comment: I meant, moving your personal .vim to .vim_backup, because the errors was coming from one of your plugins from .vim directory.